# How do you read the histone code?

Tags: biochemistry, chromatin, histone, dna-methylation

I took it upon myself to research how methylation/acetylation affects histone tails via post-translational modifications. However, I find myself confused about how to "read" this histone code, specifically for the Euchromatin.

My problem is that there are both acetylations and methylations. Does that mean that the methylation of lysine 4 will cause that portion of the chromatin to be condensed, but the acetylation of the lysine 9 and so on will cause that portion to be decondensed?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "histone code" is not like the genetic code where one codon in an ORF always is translated to a single amino acid. It's closer to something like GC content or CpG islands: a single instance doesn't tell you anything, but enrichment over some finite window may be biologically significant.

You may want to review the basics, starting with the Wikipedia page on the [histone code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histone_code). In particular read the paragraphs at the end:

> Every nucleosome in a cell can therefore have a different set of
>   modifications, raising the question of whether common patterns of
>   histone modifications exist. A recent study of about 40 histone
>   modifications across human gene promoters found over 4000 different
>   combinations used, over 3000 occurring at only a single promoter.
>   However, patterns were discovered including a set of 17 histone
>   modifications that are present together at over 3000 genes.[13]
>   Therefore, patterns of histone modifications do occur but they are
>   very intricate, and we currently have detailed biochemical
>   understanding of the importance of a relatively small number of
>   modifications.